# How to detect repeater on OnCheckedChanged event of radio button

Tags: asp.net

I have a nested repeater and there is a radiobutton in the inner one ( rptrSubscriptions ). What I want to do is to highlight the radio button that is selected and unhighlight the previous one .
There must be only one radio button selected between all of the radio buttons in the outer repeater .I also need to save the itemID of the selected one in a hidden field.

I have developed a method with the name of HighlightSubscription that will be called when user clicks on the radio button (OnCheckedChanged="HighlightSubscription") .

The problem is this, the system doesn't recognize rptrSubscriptions in HighlightSubscription method, I tried to use findcontrol but unfortunately there is no access to e.items in this method.

I also defined rptrSubscriptions as a public variable but it will be null too in this method.

I have copied the source of HighlightSubscription from HighlightBox that is a radio button inside a single repeater and it works fine as its definition is inside the designer, 
but for the nested repeater the definition cant be in the designer as the system automatically removes it in compile time.

Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

```
protected void rptrSubscriptionGroups_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    Repeater rptrSubscriptions = (Repeater)e.Item.FindControl("rptrSubscriptions");
    if (rptrSubscriptions != null)
    {
        RepeaterItem item = e.Item;
        if (e.Item.ItemType == (ListItemType.Item) || e.Item.ItemType == (ListItemType.AlternatingItem))
        {
            DataTable SubscriptionTbl = SubscriptionsBind(SelectedLanguageID, SelectedPlatformID, SelectedCurrencyID, SelectedGroupID, 1); 
            rptrSubscriptions.DataSource = SubscriptionTbl;
            rptrSubscriptions.DataBind();
        }
    }
}

protected void HighlightSubscription(object source, EventArgs e)
{
    //find previous selected row
    if (hiddenSelectedSubscriptionRowIndex.Value.Length > 0)
    {
        int rowIndex = int.Parse(hiddenSelectedSubscriptionRowIndex.Value);
        //Repeater rptrSubscriptions = (Repeater)e.Item.FindControl("rptrSubscriptions");

        RepeaterItem item = rptrSubscriptions.Items[rowIndex];

        if (rptrSubscriptions != null)
        {
            // Uncheck Old Radio Button

            RadioButton rbOld = (RadioButton)item.FindControl("rbBox");
            rbOld.Attributes.CssStyle.Add("border-color", "lightgray");
            rbOld.Attributes.CssStyle.Add("border-width", "1px");
            rbOld.Checked = false;
        }
    }
    RadioButton rb = source as RadioButton;
    int CurrentrepeaterItemIndex = ((RepeaterItem)rb.NamingContainer).ItemIndex;

    // save current row index in a hiddden field
    hiddenSelectedSubscriptionRowIndex.Value = CurrentrepeaterItemIndex.ToString();
}

<asp:Repeater ID="rptrSubscriptionGroups" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptrSubscriptionGroups_ItemDataBound" OnItemCommand="rptrSubscriptionGroups_ItemCommand">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Repeater ID="rptrSubscriptions" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptrSubscriptions_ItemDataBound" OnItemCommand="rptrSubscriptions_ItemCommand">
             <ItemTemplate>
                  <asp:RadioButton ID="rbSubscription" runat="server"  OnCheckedChanged="HighlightSubscription" AutoPostBack="true"/>
             </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little edit from me you can try this one :

```
protected void HighlightSubscription(object source, EventArgs e)
{
    Repeater rptrSubscriptions = new Repeater();
    foreach (RepeaterItem a in rptrSubscriptionGroups.Items)
    {
        rptrSubscriptions = (Repeater)a.FindControl("rptrSubscriptions");
    }

    //find previous selected row
    if (hiddenSelectedSubscriptionRowIndex.Value.Length > 0)
    {
        int rowIndex = int.Parse(hiddenSelectedSubscriptionRowIndex.Value);
        //Repeater rptrSubscriptions = (Repeater)e.Item.FindControl("rptrSubscriptions");

        RepeaterItem item = rptrSubscriptions.Items[rowIndex];

        if (rptrSubscriptions != null)
        {
            // Uncheck Old Radio Button

            RadioButton rbOld = (RadioButton)item.FindControl("rbBox");
            rbOld.Attributes.CssStyle.Add("border-color", "lightgray");
            rbOld.Attributes.CssStyle.Add("border-width", "1px");
            rbOld.Checked = false;
        }
    }
    RadioButton rb = source as RadioButton;
    int CurrentrepeaterItemIndex = ((RepeaterItem)rb.NamingContainer).ItemIndex;

    // save current row index in a hiddden field
    hiddenSelectedSubscriptionRowIndex.Value = CurrentrepeaterItemIndex.ToString();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
protected void rptrSubscriptionGroups_ItemDataCreated(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        RepeaterItem item = e.Item;

        RadioButton rb = (RadioButton)item.FindControl("rbSubscription");

        rb.AutoPostBack = true;

        rb.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(rb_CheckChanged);
    }
}

private void rb_CheckChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RadioButton rb = (RadioButton)sender;

    if(rb.Checked == true){
        HighlightSubscription();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Namrehs for your reply, as you also mentioned and I have also used  in other way ( OnCheckedChanged="HighlightSubscription" ) the HighlightSubscription is called  but the  system doesn't recognize RepeaterItem in the HighlightSubscription method.please advice.